# Linux Visual Studio Code wonky in Windows

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code

We have an unusual development environment. We're developing a Linux-based system, but our workstations are all Windows 10 boxes. We log into our Linux VMs via MobaXterm or similar tools. Some of us want to use **Visual Studio Code** as our editor.

We've already tested and used Eclipse this way, and it works perfectly. We just launch Eclipse from the Linux command-line, and Eclipse pops up on our Windows boxes. It operates just like you'd expect it to. It's nearly indistinguishable from Eclipse for Windows.

We can launch Visual Studio Code from the Linux command-line in the same fashion. Code comes up in Windows, but then it just sits there. It can't be resized, moved, or maximized. Most of us have multiple monitors, so sometimes it will appear spanning two monitors, with the "split" right in the middle of the IDE. None of the controls on the outside of the frame, such as resizing, are functional. The only button that works is the close button.

The inside of the IDE works fine. We can still edit code in and save it, but given that its so small and immovable, it's hardly practical.

One developer did a fly-by and said, "Oh, yeah. You can fix that by adjusting the X windows server settings." We've been looking at the Settings, but don't know what tweaks are required. Does anyone else have experience with this? Is MobaXterm the problem?

Comment: For me, VS Code only works over trusted (AKA insecure) X11 forwarding (`-Y` instead of `-X`).

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem with any Windows X server I tried.  The only kind-of working solution I have found is using cygwin/x in windowed mode (i.e. 'startx') which pops up all your windows in a single large window. Then resize works.  Maybe you can get windowed mode working (startxwin)?  Still looking for a good solution...